# What's a typeable symbol to indicate "starts with" in a filter field?

Tags: tables, filter, grid, symbols

I am building a custom data grid control. The users do a lot of sorting and filtering. I want them to be able to do this with only the keyboard. Currently they can filter columns by typing in the column header. They can use symbols `< > ! =` to change the filter behavior to "less than", "greater than", not, and "is exactly". If they don't use a symbol it will filter down to rows that contain the string in the column. What's a good symbol that users can type on a standard en-us keyboard that would indicate that the users want to filter down to items that start with the string they type?

Comment: Maybe simply place the string in the quotes (without any other symbols)?

Comment: Well if your users know Regular Expressions or could be generally familiar with them, ^ is the standard symbol there, but it's not intuitive otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are describing is standard wildcard functionality, so you could append a `*` to the **end** of the start string (which is nice and standard); or perhaps `+` which could be fairly intuitive; or even `%` which is used by various flavours of SQL. As well as the Regular Expression `^` as described by Ben Brocka (which would go at the start of the string).

I don't think it's a good idea to mix conventions, though. Using a `*` at the beginning of the user entry to specify "starts with" may well confuse users who are used to conventional wildcards.

**Edit following comments** If full wildcard functionality is not supported, either a `*` could stop anything else being entered, or — probably better — a tooltip could pop-up saying that only trailing wildcards are supported (and then remove the offending letter).

Comment: +1.  However, if you do not provide general wildcard support, users will probably find it confusing that `begin*` is legal but `*end` and `mid*dle` are not.

Comment: Good idea, though to stop the problems outlined by @Brian how about a lighter-colour asterisk and ellipsis that prepends whatever you type but cannot be removed? *...Query

Comment: I think I will go with full wildcard support on this. Thanks! I'll also have a context menu for setting the filter type.